# Is it possible to have tags with spaces?

Tags: ng-tags-input

I am using the ng-tags-input library, however, when my responses come back with spaces they are replaced with hyphens in the tag. Is there a way to prevent this? At a minimum can I get the original value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need `replaceSpacesWithDashes` on tags input trying now.